# SpringBoot 2 (2.1.6.RELEASE) StackOverFlowError

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot 2 application which starts and runs as expected when run in the IDE (IntelliJ).
However, when I run the app via the commandline (java -jar app.jar), I get a StackOverFlowError exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    ... 1024 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    ... 1024 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    ... 1024 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1012)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1535)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getClassLoadingLock(ClassLoader.java:463)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:404)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

The main class is as follows

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan(basePackages="x.y.z")
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
@EnableRetry
@Slf4j
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thrown when a stack overflow occurs because an application recurses too deeply.

Comment: Maybe something with circular Spring bean dependencies? But then again... Spring should recognize and this, exit, and give you a more readable error message.

Comment: @Deadpool   yes, im also thinking a circular dependency but from the logs, I cant tell what that is

Comment: Is this at startup? Can you show the relevant code, in particular all classes marked `@SpringBootApplication` and `@Configuration`?

Comment: @Codo yes it's at startup. I have edited the question to include the main class

Comment: Remove `@Configuration` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotations from your Application class

Comment: @Abhijeet doesnt make a difference

Comment: You make good use of Spring Boot features. So there are a lot of things that can go wrong. Can you post a more complete stack trace, one that shows the very bottom of the stacktrace? Have you tried disabling some of the Spring Boot features until it works, then reabling as many as possible without breaking ithe startup in order to better isolate the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the problem. This was due to the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` repackage classifier changes between version 1.5.7 and 2.1.6 ([see here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/maven-plugin/examples/repackage-classifier.html))

My 1.5.7 pom's `spring-boot-maven-plugin` was configured as follows:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
    <goals>
      <goal>build-info</goal>
      <goal>repackage</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <classifier>exec</classifier>
      <additionalProperties>
        <build.number>${buildNumber}</build.number>
      </additionalProperties>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

The resulting manifest from the build, after upgrading to `spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.16` release does not have the correct `Start-Class`.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: my-app
Implementation-Version: 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT
Start-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/
Spring-Boot-Lib: BOOT-INF/lib/
Build-Jdk-Spec: 1.8
Spring-Boot-Version: 2.1.6.RELEASE
Created-By: Maven Archiver 3.4.0
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

Changing the `spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.16` to the following fixed the issue - the jar `MANIFEST` now contains the correct `Start-Class`.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>repackage</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>build-info</goal>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>exec</classifier>
                <additionalProperties>
                    <build.number>${buildNumber}</build.number>
                </additionalProperties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Correct `MANIFEST`:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: my-app
Implementation-Version: 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT
Start-Class: my.app.MainClass
Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/
Spring-Boot-Lib: BOOT-INF/lib/
Build-Jdk-Spec: 1.8
Spring-Boot-Version: 2.1.6.RELEASE
Created-By: Maven Archiver 3.4.0
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

The app now starts fine.

Comment: I found this same issue in a brand-new Spring Boot project using v2.2.1.RELEASE. For me the solution was simply to add `<id>repackage</id>` to the maven plugin.  God knows what that changed, but without it I got the wrong Start-Class (just like the OP), with it the Start-Class was correct.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: adding <id>repackage</id> solved my issue!!! thanks @pedorro you saved my day! I was struggling with this for several days

Answer (score 2):

As for me, I added mainClass into spring boot maven plugin and MANIFEST file generated correctly.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.test.App</mainClass>
                <finalName>JarName</finalName>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```